# How do I call a function inside a struct?

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
int suma(int);
int produs(int);

struct calcul{
    int suma();
    int produs();
}
suma()=1+2+..n;// return S
produs()=1*2*..n;// return P
```

I want to call it in main with
`calcul sp`. How do I call function inside a struct?
If I give n a struct type n=5; the result to be sp(15,120).
 Thanks!!!

Comment: `suma()=1+2+..n;` This is not valid C++. What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You want to call the function inside the struct?

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages! Pick one!

Comment: Thats not valid code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want something like:

```
struct calcul
{
    int suma(int n)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
            result += n;
        return result;
    }
    //... similar for produs
};

int main()
{
     calcul sp;
     int x = sp.suma(10);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int suma(int);
int produs(int);
```

and

```
struct calcul{
    int suma();
    int produs();
};
```

are two completely different sets of functions, even though they have the same name. The functions in your struct are member functions and can only be called on an instance of your struct. You would do it like so:

```
int main()
{
    calcul x;
    int a = x.suma(0);
    int b = x.produs(1);
}
```